# Reading all the files in a directory in Python

Tags: python, search

I have a bunch of files in the same directory named `halo_track*.dat`. Each file has two columns. For every file, I want to find the value `1.0015` in the left column, read off the value to the right of it, and append it to a list. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glob` and `fileinput` are one way (untested)

```
from glob import glob
import fileinput

filenames = glob('halo_track*.dat')
inputs = (line.split(None, 1) for line in fileinput.input(filenames))
right_stuff = [col[1] for col in inputs if col[0] == '1.0015']
```

Comment: @mcglashan It should work - you are using `glob('/path/to/your/dir/halo_track_*.dat')` or similar ? (just do a `print filenames` and see if that's returning what you expect it to contain)

Comment: Now it does. It was a mistake on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat halo_track*.dat | grep "^1.0015" | cut -f2 > alist.txt
```

you don't need python here. for cut, you might also need to specify -d if the delimiter is not a tab.